# How to simulate tablet pressure is sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I don't have tablet, but I need to make Blender change brush radius dynamicly, depending on mouse speed. Is there any way to do this? Maybe some third-party software that able to do this?

I'm already tried [this addon](https://github.com/jeacom25b/Blender-Pressure-Simulate-Addon) but that's not exactly what I need (and also it doesn't work)

Comment: Do you need it in the sculpt- or texture paint-mode?

Comment: I need this in sculpt mode, and this addon actually created to be working in sculpt mode. And i'm not that much about Python to redact it